# Python Flask send data and get that data from another computer

Tags: python, flask

I am having trouble the getting data from the website. I coded the program that sends the data(data is = 1:50) to 0.0.0.0 and my other computer(which is raspberry pi) can read the data in web browser.

I just want the read this 1:50 data in my raspberry pi and want to process it. When i am looking at it the examples telling about the web scrape and parsing from  i have no div only in message body is there any other way or how can i do that.

Sending Data:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
data1 = "1"
data2 = "50"
@app.route('/')

def display():
    return data1+":"+data2
if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True, threaded=True)
```

Receiving Side:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://192.168.1.myip:5000/"
html = urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser")


for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
    script.extract()    


text = soup.get_text()


print(text)
```

Comment: Hello! can you please add some of your code or the html file of your website and your code being used to scrape it, It would make it a lot easier to actually find your issue. :)

Comment: Hello, edited the sending and receiving code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your "sending data" area, you are actually making a web server. I don't know much about Raspberry pis, but you should be able to send a request to the server, and get the data back.

**Hosting the web server**

There is one wrench to overcome though. In order to send a request to this server, you need somewhere to host it. Basically, you need to find a space on a huge internet server to handle all the requests from clients coming through.

There are a few services for hosting that are free, like GitHub Pages or Repl.it Online IDE. Plop your server into one of those, and send a request to the URL generated.

**Sending the request**
`urllib` is more of an unused library now, and has been more or less replaced with the new `requests` module. This puppy is the real deal. You can send all sorts of requests with a very small code footprint. There is no point in using `beautifulsoup` for this, as when you send the request, you get only the text returned.

```
import requests
resp = requests.get('yoururl.com')
txt = resp.content
print(txt)
```